# Javascript - After creating a div, Ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a button for a form. When I click the button, the form is created. After being created, the form is not working with Ajax. My script codes are in here. My `#testform` is not wrong because it's working without creating form. Do you have any ideas?

```js
function addDiv() {
  var panel = document.querySelector(".add_new");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = '<br> <form id="testform" method="POST">  <div class="row" style="padding-left:10rem;">  <div class="col-md-4"> <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Başlık" name="yeniBaslik" required></div> <div class="col-md-4"> <input type="text" placeholder="Açıklama" name="yeniAciklama" class="form-control" value="" name="" required> </div>   <div class="col-md-2 text-left">  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-animated btn-wide addToDatabase">Add to the Database</button>  </div>  </row> </form> <br>';
  panel.appendChild(div);
}

$("#testform").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($("#testform").get(0));
  $.ajax({
    url: 'config.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function() {
      setTimeout(
        function() {
          $(".addToDatabase").html("Successfully.");
        }, 1000);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addDiv()"> Create a form </button>

<div class="add_new"></div>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Please share any error messages you are getting, or describe the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since second statement is executed before "div" is created, submit event is not being listened to on the new `<form>`

```
function addDiv() {
   /*...*/
  panel.appendChild(div);
  $("#testform").submit(function(e) { /*...*/ });
}
```